# Multiple purchase using single google play account?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, in-app-purchase

I'm new to google play in app purchase. I have created an app that connects on my back-end server. After installing the app to an android device, user can login with different account that they created in my webserver regardless of what google account was logged-in in their android phone. Can I use the same google account to purchase non consumable item from any of the account logged-in using my own authentication? I'm thinking of saving the purchased item to my webserver after google play purchase successful callback. But the problem is when the buyer make a refund? since I have no way of checking who's account in my webserver it is. What is the best way of doing this? I only want the IAP of google play, I don't want to restrict user to have an google account or change google account in my phone when I log in to my own account in my webserver. Sorry if its unclear.

Comment: It's not very clear to me but a google account can be used only once to purchase that non consumable item. Once you have purchased a item X from google account ABC . You cannot buy that item X again from that same google account ABC

Comment: May be use Google Account.